# generate uml sequence diagrams with python or perl

Tags: python, perl, uml, sequence-diagram

I have some text which I will process to generate a **uml sequence diagram** image. I can process the text in `python` or `perl` into a format of an existing 'text to uml' tools but I'm trying to eliminate that extra step and give the image output directly from the python/perl script.

Are there any python or perl packages/modules I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several perl modules which do this in Perl, see [UML::State](https://metacpan.org/module/UML%3a%3aState).

From the synopsis:

```
use UML::State;

my $diagram = UML::State->new(
  $node_array,
  $start_list,
  $accept_list,
  $edges
);

# You may change these defaults (doing so may even work):
$UML::State::ROW_SPACING = 75;  # all numbers are in pixels
$UML::State::LEFT_MARGIN = 20;
$UML::State::WIDTH       = 800;
$UML::State::HEIGHT      = 800;

print $diagram->draw();
```

CPAN is your friend.:)

Comment: I think this one is for state diagrams but I also found [UML::Sequence](http://search.cpan.org/~philcrow/UML-Sequence-0.08/lib/UML/Sequence.pm) in the same page for sequence diagrams, thanks..

Comment: @gokcehan whoops sorry for the mixup, but yes, if you want it chances are there is a CPAN module for it

Comment: can't install these for some reason. might be just I'm new to CPAN. can anyone confirm this?

Comment: I installed them alright, try `sudo cpanm UML::State` if on linux

Comment: `cpanm` looks much easier than `cpan`, thanks. I was able to install `UML::State` but `UML::Sequence` is still giving a configuration error and bailing out.

Comment: `Configuring GD-2.46 ... N/A
! Configure failed for GD-2.46. See /home/gokce/.cpanm/build.log for details.
! Bailing out the installation for UML-Sequence-0.08. Retry with --prompt or --f
orce.
`

Comment: @gokcehan Did you check the log?

Comment: looks like I had a problem with `libgd`. I cleaned all modules from the old `cpan` and reinstalled everything with `cpanm`. now I've got another error, `Building and testing UML-Sequence-0.08 ... FAIL` and `build.log` says `failed 3/10 test programs..`

Comment: @Petri See the first comment, UML::Sequence is also a module. It's a little late to be complaining now

Comment: @jozefg - well, why not change your answer then accordingly?

Answer (score 9):

There are many Python alternatives.

If you want to generate images from scratch, you may want to consider [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (Python Imaging Library), the "de facto" image library for Python.

However, for sequence diagrams in particular, the blockdiag diagram images generator library (that uses PIL as well) includes a sequence diagram generator called [seqdiag](http://blockdiag.com/en/seqdiag/index.html). For example, here's how to define & produce a simple but complete sequence diagram, *including* the diagram definition:

```
from seqdiag import parser, builder, drawer

diagram_definition = u"""
   seqdiag {
      browser  -> webserver [label = "GET /index.html"];
      browser <- webserver;
   }
"""
tree = parser.parse_string(diagram_definition)
diagram = builder.ScreenNodeBuilder.build(tree)
draw = drawer.DiagramDraw('PNG', diagram, filename="diagram.png")
draw.draw()
draw.save()
```

See http://blockdiag.com/en/seqdiag/examples.html for some more example (sequence) diagram definitions and styling options.

Comment: looks like just what I needed. I will give this one a try first as I'm more familiar with python than perl, thanks..

Comment: I tried to run from command line and it works great but how do I use it within a script? I have tried importing the module but it doesn't seem to have any functions or classes. I suppose I could create a subprocess but I would need to give a file output for that first which would rule out the whole point of doing this..

Comment: The blockdiag google group seems to have some instructions: see for example https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/blockdiag-discuss/rXHXM9AoELQ.

Comment: that seems to be working only for `blockdiag`. I have asked the discussion group about `seqdiag`. let's see what they say, thanks..

Comment: @gokcehan, if you review the above example, you'll note it generates a sequence diagram. Isn't that what you asked for? Under the hood, seqdiag is actually just a thin wrapper on top of blockdiag.

Comment: it looks like a `seqdiag` because you have defined it as such in the string but actually it ignores that `seqdiag` and renders it as a blockdiag. you can try it by saving that string to en external file and using command line `blockdiag` and `seqdiag` commands to render it. your code produces the same picture as `blockdiag` command which is not a sequence diagram but a regular one. You can also try more complex examples from the page you linked, it will fail to parse them as well.

Comment: ah, sorry, I simply forgot to change the import. Fixed now. Note also that if you use labels (as in example), the diagram definition must be unicode (also fixed in the example).

Comment: I will try using this in conjonction with traceback (https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html)